AzureStorage Blob Server failing. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
I have this php function that generates a Shared Access Signature token to access resources in my Azure Storage Container, but it isn't working properly.
function generateSasToken($accountName, $accountKey, $blobName, $containerName, $expiryTime = '+1 hour') {
        // Get current UTC time and expiry time (in ISO 8601 format)
        $start = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'); // Current time in UTC format
        $expiry = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($expiryTime)); // Expiry time in UTC format
        
        // Construct the URL for the blob (to be used in SAS token)
        $url = "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";

        // Set SAS parameters
        $permissions = 'r'; // Read permissions
        $services = 'b'; // Blob service
        $resource = 'c'; // Container resource
        $protocol = 'https'; // Protocol (HTTPS only)
        $version = '2022-11-02'; // API version

        // Build the string to sign (format: [permissions] \n [services] \n [resource] \n [start] \n [expiry] \n [protocol] \n [version])
        $stringToSign = "$permissions\n$services\n$containerName\n$start\n$expiry\n$protocol\n$version";
        
        // Decode the account key from base64 (used for HMAC calculation)
        $decodedAccountKey = base64_decode($accountKey);
        
        // Generate the signature using HMAC-SHA256
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $decodedAccountKey, true));
        
        // Build the full SAS token with all required parameters
        $sasToken = "sv=$version&ss=$services&srt=$resource&sp=$permissions&se=$expiry&st=$start&spr=$protocol&sig=" . urlencode($signature);

        // Return the full SAS URL
        return "$url?$sasToken";
    }

I'm getting an error if I try to copy the SAS URL and test it in a browser manually stating the following:
AuthenticationFailed
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. ...
Signature did not match. String to sign used was ...

Using SAS token either you need to download blob or list the blobs? can you share the URL you tried?

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


I have this php function that generates a Shared Access Signature token to access resources in my Azure Storage Container, but it isn't working properly.

You can use the below code that generate SAS token for Azure storage container.
Code:
<?php

// Mock variables for demonstration
$containerName = "test";
$accessKey = "xxxxx";

// Function to generate SAS token
function generateSas($storageAccountKey, $input) {
    $keyBytes = base64_decode($storageAccountKey);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $input, $keyBytes, true);
    $hashB64 = base64_encode($hash);
    $hashB64UriEncoded = rawurlencode($hashB64);

    return $hashB64UriEncoded;
}

function generateSasToken() {
    global $containerName, $accessKey;

    $currentDate = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $expiration = clone $currentDate;
    $expiration->modify('+120 minutes');

    $signedStart = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $signedExpiry = $expiration->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

    $signedPermissions = "r";
    $signedService = "c";
    $signedProtocol = "https";
    $signedVersion = "2022-11-02";
    $accountname = "venkat326123";
    $canonicalizedResource = "/blob/{$accountname}/{$containerName}";

    $stringToSign = "{$signedPermissions}\n{$signedStart}\n{$signedExpiry}\n{$canonicalizedResource}\n\n\n{$signedProtocol}\n{$signedVersion}\n{$signedService}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    $signature = generateSas($accessKey, $stringToSign); // Generate signature using generateSas function
    $sasToken = "sv={$signedVersion}&sr={$signedService}&sp={$signedPermissions}&st={$signedStart}&se={$signedExpiry}&spr={$signedProtocol}&sig={$signature}";

    echo "https://{$accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{$containerName}/?{$sasToken}" . PHP_EOL;
}

generateSasToken();

?>

Output:
PS xxxx> php sample.php
https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/?sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sp=r&st=2024-11-08T04:20:15Z&se=2024-11-08T06:20:15Z&spr=https&sig=redacted


Request:
Verified with API request and got the content of the blob in the specified container, as shown below.

